# Permission to change certain property

Tags: permissions

Is it possible to **only** give **certain** users (or user group) the permission to change a property?

for a school project we need to set up a sharepoint where some (2) properties of a document set can only be changed by certain users (group). Other users can make the document set and set up it's properties except for those (2) properties.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add those properties to a different list
2. Use those values as lookup column in library
3. break permission on the list and give acess to users who should be updating those 2 properties

There's also a codeplex solution available:

https://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com

Comment: the problem is its a date (each document set is a case which has an end and start date), will this also work your way?

also it's the property of the document set not really a column

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. I would recommend you to solve with custom development as either Client or Server Object Model.

Two possible steps:

1. Hide the properties so that they can not be changed from the
   standard form.
2. Create a screen to edit the properties. In your
   code, you can check the permissions previously.

Comment: Thinking of Custom Development[Editing the edit form] . Will using Nintex forms be a good solution ?? Based on users permission , you can create rules to hide/show columns or display a read only fields for all properties except 2 fields for certain user groups and then show all to rest of the people. But the irony is , Nintex Forms does not support Document Set.

Comment: would it be possible to hide the field in the content type when making a new document set but make it so that some users can acces the properties (after the document set's been made) and set the 2 properties (fields) there?

Comment: @MpArvind so it's possbile with document libraries but not with document sets?

Comment: yes @SethVerfaillie ! You can build custom forms using Nintex Forms on Document Libraries . It is quite similar to the Infopath forms . What version of SharePoint are you using ?